# Why when I press the reset button

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, bootloader

Why when I press the reset button it takes 2 second before I see my sketch start? 
The model of Arduino is UNO, and the text in serial communication.

Comment: This is not a particularly helpful question. Reset button on **what Arduino model?** What is "**some time**"? A second? A minute? What is "**output**"? Text in the serial monitor? An LED flashing?

Comment: The model of Arduino is UNO and it takes 2-3 second and the text in the serial monitor. The output is the Sketch. I will say the question again Why when I press the reset button it takes 2 second before my Sketch stast?

Comment: Please edit your question to improve it with this new information. The question should stand on its own without having to skim through the comments. Thanks! And welcome to Arduino StackExchange. :)

Answer (score 3):

Because first the bootloader is executed and takes 2 seconds (or more on a Leonardo) to time out when it doesn't receive a proper response from the computer.

Comment: You can set the fuses on the processor to not run the bootloader, in which case it will start a lot faster. However uploading sketches then is harder, as you have to use ICSP programming to do that.

Comment: Thanks for replay, but can tell me the reason of why it takes some time to start sketch ?

Comment: Because first the bootloader is executed and takes 2 seconds (or more on a Leonardo) to time out when it doesn't receive a proper response from the computer.